# stop fixed element from scrolling into the footer when the browser window is a smaller height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have tried the below jQuery / logic but it's not working... The problem is I have a fixed nav, and that's fine. But when the user is on a smaller height resolution / screen ie. a laptop the fixed scrolling nav, when scrolled to the bottom of the page -- overlaps the footer element. Which looks really bad.

The below is not working.. and seems to only, revert my fixed element to position absolute immediately on page load.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    function checkOffset() {
     if($('.navSmall').offset().top + $('.navSmall').height() 
                                       >= $('#footer-wrapper-4o').offset().top - 10)
    $('.navSmall').css('position', 'absolute');
     if($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight < $('#footer-wrapper-4o').offset().top)
    $('.navSmall').css('position', 'fixed'); // restore when you scroll up
    $('.navSmall').text($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight);
  }
  $(document).scroll(function() {
      checkOffset();
  });
  });
```

**P.S.** Could there be a way I could incorporate a stopping point by simple using a div `<div class="stop"></div>` and once the fixed / scrolling element hits  then it can't continue past that point?

Comment: Can you please upload of a photo of what it looks like or a jsfiddle we can tinker with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function checkOffset() {....}

$(window).load(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      checkOffset();
  });
}
```

It's better use function in this way.